# Creating a matrix of options using itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to produce a matrix of True and False values, which shows all the permutations for a given number of choices.  So for 5 choices you would have the following output.

```
F F F F F
T F F F F
T T F F F
T T T F F
...
F T F F F
...
```

I have been looking at using itertool's permutations and combinations, but these work off position and not value which results in duplicates.

I'm sure there is a standard algorithm for this problem, but I'm struggling to find its name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
itertools.product([False,True],repeat=5)
```

example of `itertools.product([False,True],repeat=2)`:

```
(False, False)
(False, True)
(True, False)
(True, True)
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to want the n-dimensional cartesian product of `[False, True]`.

```
>>> print list(itertools.product(*(itertools.repeat((False, True), 3))))
[(False, False, False), (False, False, True), (False, True, False), 
 (False, True, True), (True, False, False), (True, False, True), 
 (True, True, False), (True, True, True)]
```

Or more concisely (stealing from [Frederick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046178/creating-a-matrix-of-options-using-itertools/7046341#7046341))

```
>>> print list(itertools.product((False, True), repeat=3))
[(False, False, False), (False, False, True), (False, True, False), 
(False, True, True), (True, False, False), (True, False, True), 
(True, True, False), (True, True, True)]
```

Comment: Wow, that was just what I was after thanks.  Please could you explain a little of what is happening there for a Python newbie?  Is that * still acting as a multiplication operator?

Comment: No, that unpacks the result of `itertools.repeat`. (Say you have `def foo(a, b, c)`. Then you can pass a sequence to `foo` like so `foo(*(a, b, c))` instead of passing in the args individually.) I forgot about the `repeat` keyword arg.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same form as the binary representation of integers between 0 to (2**n)-1. If you were inclined to such perversity, you *could* represent integers as zero-padded binary strings using str.format() and then coerce the string (of the form "00101") into a boolean list by doing something terrible like this:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> for i in xrange(2**n):
...     [bool(int(j)) for j in ("{0:0>%db}" % n).format(i)]
```

The n-dimensional Cartesian product above is, I'm sure, the right way to think about this, but  this way made me giggle.

Comment: This is probably horribly ineffecient, as you clearly recognize, but conceptually very important to know! +1 for that.

Comment: `[bool(i & 2**j) for j in range(n)]` also works and don't require string formatting...